# Google App always opens google.com on chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android, google, google-apps, samsung-galaxy-s-8

When I open the Google App, it promptly opens Chrome and switches to google.com. I cannot access anything on Google App since it immediately switches to Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Same happened on my sister's Samsung Tablet. Turned out it was caused by the Qustodio Parental Control app. It blocked safe search which was forcing the Google app to open google search in Chrome because google would not allow the parental control app to enforce safe search and monitor its app .

Don't know if its that but here is Qustodio help article telling that : 
https://www.qustodio.com/en/help/article/2832549/ (under heading "Safe searches on Android")

If you don't have Qustodio Parental Control app, maybe it could be some other app that high control on your device. Qustodio shows at this link what i mean by high control (ex. Apps with usage access, Accessibility, etc) - go to the step called "11. When prompted to Activate app supervision, choose Activate Now.".

Answer (score 0):

Actually from the looks of things, Google has implemented Chrome custom tabs feature. The Google app now opens search results as Chrome Custom Tabs.

According to [Google Search help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/7013866?hl=en):

> You can open web pages directly inside the Google app on your Android
>   device. This lets you:
>
> - Open search result links faster
> - Stay in the Google app
> - Copy or share a link, re-open a link in your browser, and more

To be able to *open web pages in app* you need:

- **Google app version 5.12+**
- To go to Settings > Accounts & privacy to toggle on the new ‘Open web pages in app’ option:

[image]

*Pic source Reddit*

If the above conditions are met try troubleshooting by

- *Clearing app defaults* in Settings

  1. Open your device's Settings app Settings.
  2. Under "Device," tap Apps .
  3. Tap the app that you no longer want to be the default (i.e Chrome)
  4. Tap Open by default and then clear defaults.
- Clear Google app cache and(or) data
  (Settings >> Apps >> Google App >> Clear cache/data)

Comment: I cannot even access the settings for the Google App, since Chrome launches immediately to Google.com. I am not searching anything, in fact, I'm not doing anything on the Google App except opening it.

Comment: Try troubleshooting steps I mentioned above, and please report back additionally clear data for Chrome

Comment: It took a while and Google apps opened 30+ Chrome tabs of Google.com, but I was able to turn "open web pages in app" on. Chrome doesn't automatically open, but I still get a prompt asking which web browser to open with (Chrome, or Samsung Internet). Something is forcing Google App to open the google.com web page.

Comment: Yes, quite strange though I will update once I figure the root cause